# Can I register a BroadcastReceiver in code which is raised by a explicit Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I've learnt that `BroadcastReceiver` has to be declare in `AndroidManifest.xml` or registered in code like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("some_action");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

But if I want to use a explicit `Intent`(which does not have `IntentFilter`s) to start the `BroadcastReceiver`, how should I register it in code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"use a explicit Intent(witch does not have IntentFilters) to start the Receiver"_?

Comment: Like:  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);   then use  PendingIntent.getBroadcast() to trigger the BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. An explicit `Intent` will only work with a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: thanks for telling me that, seems I have to declare it in the xml.