# How does a manifest registered BroadcastReceiver interact with other objects?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a manifest registered BroadcastReceiver which receives repeat alarms from an AlarmManager, I want to notify a Service when an alarm received, I'm thinking about set a listener to the BroadcastReceiver and call the listener like this:

```
public class HeartbeatAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private OnAlarmReceivedListener mListener;

    public interface OnAlarmReceivedListener {
        /**
         * Callback to call when a heart beat alarm received.
         */
        public void onHeartBeatAlarmReceived();
    }

    public HeartbeatAlarmReceiver(OnAlarmReceivedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mListener.onHeartBeatAlarmReceived();
    }
}
```

However, this requires a constructor with parameter to set the listener, but manifest registered BroadcastReceiver seems to be initiated by a default constructor. I know I can register the receiver in the code by giving an IntentFilter, but for some reason I must use an explicit Intent to start the receiver, which means I must declare it in the manifest. (see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830792/can-i-register-a-broadcastreceiver-in-code-which-is-raised-by-a-explicit-intent)**)   so what should I do?

Comment: **"I want to notify a Service when an alarm received"** : OK, so just call `context.startService(...)` in the `onReceive(...)` method passing an `Intent` with any data as the `Intent` extras.

Comment: "For some reason I must use an explicit Intent to start the receiver". Why is that?

Comment: for security consideration. Because an implicit intent can be send by other application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Your BroadcastReceiver can call your service. Use `context.startService(intent)`.
2. When you make the PendingIntent for your alarm, you can make it for the Service directly instead of for the BroadcastReceiver. Use `PendingIntent.getService(...)`